# Android: missing feature watch error

Tags: android, mobile, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I developed wear app and mobile app separate with the same package name. After that I embedded the signed wear apk to the Mobile app SDK.

After embedded when I try to run into mobile am getting an error "MISSING features watch"

**For embedded am following** 
1. Copy the signed wearable app to your handheld project's **res/raw** directory
2. Create a **res/xml/wearable_app_desc.xml**

```
<wearableApp package="wearable.app.package.name">
<versionCode>1</versionCode>
<versionName>1.0</versionName>
<rawPathResId>wearable_app</rawPathResId> 
</wearableApp>
```

3. Add a meta-data tag to your handheld app's **application** tag

   Am not getting why the issue occurs.am using all the user permission which i used in the wear sdk in mobile sdk

Please help me to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
I don't know whether you are giving the below feature tag in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file in the wearable app module. If not, please give it which will solve your problem.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"/>
```

Solution 2:
If you are having different flavours for your mobile app and **having only one flavour for the wear app**, you need to use the application id of the flavour you used in mobile app in the wear app.

For example: Say you are having two flavors for mobile app 
1. com.wear.app.prod
2. com.wear.app.dev

If you are using **com.wear.app.prod**, the same should be used for your wear app. If you changed to **com.wear.app.dev**, then the application id of the wear app should be changed to **com.wear.app.dev**.

**Note:** This is for apps having only one flavour for wear app and multiple flavours for the mobile app.

Comment: when i remove the <uses-feature> tag from manifest the apk is installed in mobile. I dont know is it needed or not @Madhan

Answer (score 0):

in android studio beside device chose, you can chose your package, select the app , not the wear module and run the project.
[image]